Moq unable to resolve methods with same name but one being generic
I have 2 methods is the base abstract class:
public abstract class BaseHttpService
{
......
        protected async Task<T> Post<T>(string url, object? payload, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(url));

            url = $"{_baseUrl}/{url}/";

            return await Send<T>(CreateMessage(url, payload, HttpMethod.Post), cancellationToken);
        }

        protected async Task Post(string url, object? payload, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(url));

            url = $"{_baseUrl}/{url}/";

            await Send(CreateMessage(url, payload, HttpMethod.Post), cancellationToken);
        }
......
}

and a subclass inheriting from this base class:
public class HttpGovPayService : BaseHttpService, IHttpGovPayService
{

.................
public async Task<GovPayResponseDto> InitiatePaymentAsync(GovPayRequestDto paymentRequestDto, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (_bearerToken != null)
    {
        SetBearerToken(_bearerToken); // Set the bearer token
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(ExceptionMessages.BearerTokenNull);
    }

    var url = UrlConstants.GovPayInitiatePayment;
    try
    {
        // Use the retry policy when calling the Post method
        return await _retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
        {
            return await Post<GovPayResponseDto>(url, paymentRequestDto, cancellationToken);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ExceptionMessages.ErrorInitiatingPayment, ex);
    }
}
....................
}

Now while testing the retry mechanism, I'm setting up the Post method but keep getting "Sequence contains more than one matching element" and that is because Moq is not able distinguish between Post<T> and Post methods. Both have the same signature but one is not generic. Is there any way to fix this? I should not be changing the code because the tests can't be created so interested to know if there is anything I can change in the tests. The test snippet is below:
var service = new Mock<HttpGovPayService>(
            _httpContextAccessorMock.Object,
            _httpClientFactoryMock.Object,
            _configMock.Object
        )
        {
            CallBase = true // Use actual implementation for non-mocked methods
        };


        service.Protected()
               .Setup<Task<GovPayResponseDto>>("Post", ItExpr.IsAny<string>(),
               ItExpr.IsAny<GovPayRequestDto>(),
               ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
               .Callback(() => postMethodCallCount++)
               .Returns(() =>
               {
                   if (postMethodCallCount < 3)
                   {
                       throw mockException; // Throw exception on the first two calls
                   }
                   Task.FromResult(mockResponse);  // Return mockResponse on the third call
               });


You are calling the incorrect overload of the Setup method to configure your mock. The overload you need must also specify the generic type. For example:
service.Protected()
    .Setup<Task<GovPayResponseDto>>(
        "Post", 
        new[] { typeof(GovPayResponseDto) }, // << The generic type goes here
        true, // Force an exact parameter match
        ItExpr.IsAny<string>(), ItExpr.IsAny<object?>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())


That's amazing !!! @DavidG, I went pass the problem but getting the error:
No protected method HttpGovPayService.Post found whose signature is compatible with the provided arguments (Type[], string, GovPayRequestDto, CancellationToken).
Is it because HttpGovPayService inherits from BaseHttpService and Moq is only looking for a method directly in HttpGovPayService . It shouldn't happen though.

Looking at your method, I'd say the second parameter should be of type object? and not GovPayRequestDto.

I couldn't write my response here due to length and formatting so added a comment below. Let me know your thoughts

That's correct. In addition to that I had to do 2 things;

Use ReturnsAsync like:
        .ReturnsAsync(() =>
        {
            if (postMethodCallCount < 3)


Made Post method virtual in code (which I do not like and would welcome if I do not have to do this). If I do not make the method virtual in code then I am getting the following error;
"Unsupported expression: mock => mock.Post(It.IsAny(), It.IsAny(), It.IsAny())
Non-overridable members (here: BaseHttpService.Post) may not be used in setup / verification expressions."


